# How .extension readers are made?

Tags: file, pdf, web

For example, there are many pdf readers in the market and they are not from Adobe. So, how do they make the readers(viewers) for these extensions?
I want to make an online application which has an ability to view these formats:
pdf,
word,
powerpoint,
is there special libraries or frameworks to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will either search for the official file format and implement a viewer for it, or they will try to reverse engineer the file formats and make a viewer for it.

For PDF, the file format has always been publicly shared by Adobe so others could implement viewers (and more); Adobe still makes their version of the specification public here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html. Meanwhile, the PDF file format became an international standard through the ISO as ISO 32000 so the latest version of the PDF specification can also be gotten through the ISO or your countries standards organisation (if it is member of the ISO community).

For Word and PowerPoint, you would have to find the information from Microsoft. These file formats are proprietary file formats and certainly for the beginning of their life, no public documentation (that I'm aware of) existed. The later formats have been (at least partially) made public by Microsoft) - how complete that support is I'm not aware of.

As to your second point - how would you implement this, there are basically two ways to do this:

1) You can write everything from scratch. That is certainly feasible for PDF; some tens of companies have done so.

2) You could use the (very many) man years of work these companies have put in this by using an existing library that supports the file format. Libraries exist both on the open source, free and commercial level which implement support for all or a partial list of features in these file formats.